# Hibernate support REST Compression

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to solve one problem as part of rest API

URIs :

```
  /sudents?fields=id,name,books

  /students?fields=id,name,books,rollNo,address
```

In hibernate `Student` is a parent entity. `Address` is an `@onetoone` mapping with lazy loading and books is an `@onetomany` mapping with lazy loading.

Is there a way in hibernate to populate the student object with the list of requested fields? I have used `Projection` to populate the normal and `@onetoone` mapping fields. But in case of `@onetomany` (collection), I am finding it difficult..

Is there a practice in hibernate to solve this problem as user can request any field.?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

So you want the list of book objects to be loaded along with student entity. In that case you can do `Hibernate.initialize(student.getBooks());`To get the list of books associated with the students. Does that solve your problem ?

Comment: in that case, I would rather use `criteria.setFetchMode("resources", FetchMode.JOIN);`. Both of these solve the lazy loading association to be part of the parent object rather than proxy. My other problem is to retrieve only selected fields and bind with the object.. That is something I solved using `Projection`

Comment: You can use direct HQL query to project your data. `String hql = "Select FieldName1, FieldName2 From Table where id = parentId"; Query query = currentSession().createQuery(hql);  List<Child> list = list(query);`